# In Sql Server 2014 ORDER BY clause with OFFSET FETCH NEXT returns weird results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently using Sql Server 2014 Professional and the current version is (12.0.4100). I have a View and I am trying to SELECT 10 rows with specific offset.
My View is like below:

```
    BeginTime   |     EndTime    | Duration |   Name   
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    1     | some_name1
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    2     | some_name2
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    3     | some_name3
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    4     | some_name4
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    5     | some_name5
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    6     | some_name6
09:00:00.0000000|16:00:00.0000000|    7     | some_name7
```

there are 100 rows like these and all have the exact same value in `BeginTime` and `EndTime`. Duration is incremented from 1 to 100 in related table.
 If query is only:

```
SELECT * FROM View_Name
```

ResultSet is correct. I can understand it by checking the duration column.
If I want to fetch only 10 rows starting from 0, ResultSet is correct and it is correct for starting from up to 18. When I want to fetch 10 rows starting from 19 or more than 19, Duration in ResultSet returns irrelevant results like Duration reversed. But it never returns the rows which has duration more than 11.
 The query that I used to fetch specific rows is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM View_Name ORDER BY BeginTime ASC OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

There is also something strange in this situation; if I specify `USE master`, this problem disappears, but, if I specify `USE [mydb_name]`, the problem appears again. 
By the way, I am using SQL SERVER 2014 Professional v(12.0.2269) in my local pc, this problem disappears for the above situation.
PS: I can not use `USE master` because, I am creating and listing the view dynamically, in Stored Procedures.
 Any help, answer or comment will be accepted. 
 Thank You!

Answer (score 15):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) explains:

> To achieve stable results between query requests using `OFFSET` and
>   `FETCH`, the following conditions must be met:
>
> . . .
>
> 2. The `ORDER BY` clause contains a column or combination of columns that are guaranteed to be unique.

What happens in your case is that `BeginTime` is not unique.  Databases in general -- and SQL Server in particular -- do not implement stable sorts.  A stable sort is one where the rows are in the same order when the keys are the same.  This is rather obvious, because tables and result sets represent unordered sets.  They have no inherent ordering.

So, you need a unique key to make the sort stable.  Given your data, this would seem to be either `duration`, `name`, or both:

```
SELECT * 
ROM View_Name
ORDER BY BeginTime ASC, Duration, Name
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thanks for Response Mr. Linoff, that was helpful and works very well.But, what if, the view has no unique column inside it? The views are displayed dynamicaly in my web application. And also; why this problem disappears while using master?

Comment: @AlicanUzun . . . Just because the query seems to work, does not mean that it works *consistently*.

Answer (score 1):

your order by should be unique,otherwise you will get indeterministic results(in your case  ,begin time is not unique and your are not guarnteed to get same results every time).try changing your query to below to make it unique..

```
SELECT * FROM View_Name ORDER BY duration OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Further to add ,your first query (select * from view) result set is not guaranteed to be accurate every time unless you have an outer order by .

Comment: please clarify on what is correct and not correct,i assume with first query you are getting correct results(which is also not guranteed unless you have an outer order by ) and with offset and fetch you are not getting the same.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM View_Name ORDER BY BeginTime ASC` returns correct order! For your attention.

Comment: could you please post the expected resulst and actual results for your two queries.I assume when you use master,you are using three part naming convention

Comment: expected result is the same order like view created first time. And also, result set is same for every offset after 18.