# SQL SERVER - FETCH NEXT ROWS returns duplicate results

Tags: sql-server

I had a very weird issue in my website, and finally I succeeded to pinpoint the exact cause.

In my 'Entities' table I have several columns, such as "Id", "Title", "Date", "Indexing" and some more.

"Indexing" column indexed with full-text index.

Consider the following SQL query:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM [dbo].[Entities] AS DocTable 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Entities, Indexing, 'otherCriteria OR criteia') AS KEY_TBL  
ON DocTable.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC
```

This query works as expected and I getting around 600 results.

Now I adding pagination:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM [dbo].[Entities] AS DocTable 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Entities, Indexing, 'otherCriteria OR criteia') AS KEY_TBL  
ON DocTable.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC 
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

No matter if I using OFFSET 30 or 40 or 50 -> I always getting exactly the same results!

Now the really weird part: if inside SELECT I asking to select 'Title' also (e.g. SELECT Id, Title) --> I getting correct results.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think RANK is meant to be used this way... Why not just order by ID?

Comment: I need to sort by relevance

Comment: what happens if you dump the results into a temp table first, then paginate off of the temptable?

Comment: Double check if your table Rank field is set as a Key for `CLUSTERED`.

Comment: Can you post a script that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I think I got it

[In Sql Server 2014 ORDER BY clause with OFFSET FETCH NEXT returns weird results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184267/in-sql-server-2014-order-by-clause-with-offset-fetch-next-returns-weird-results)

Says:

> The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination of columns that
>   are guaranteed to be unique.

Obviously, "RANK" is not unique. When I changed my query to:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM [dbo].[Entities] AS DocTable 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Entities, Indexing, 'otherCriteria OR criteia') AS KEY_TBL  
ON DocTable.Id = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC, Id
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I received correct results

Comment: problem still exist in Sql Server 2019