# Slow CTE Subquery in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, common-table-expression, database-performance

I have a Query which takes on my SQL 2008 DB 1.4 seconds. Then I tried to do a subquery using this template:

```
;with __myResults as (
    ... my initial query ... already has a column:
    row_number() over (ORDER BY ...) as RowNum
)
select * from __myResults where RowNum between X and Y
```

If I set X and Y to low numbers, it performs well. It takes about 0.3 seconds.
If I set X and Y to high numbers, it performs even worse than the initial query. It constantly increases in runtime, if I increase X and Y.

How can this be?

What I tried to do is compare the execution plan, but they were the same (just looking at the "Cost: n%")

How do I debug this? Where do I see where the problems are?

I also tried the following:

```
where RowNum > highNumber
```

is fast! whereas

```
where RowNum > highNumber and RowNum < highNumber + 10
```

is slow. And finally:

```
where RowNum < highNumber
```

is very slow (6 seconds).

**Update**

I ended up putting the results in a temp table. And do the filtering afterwards. It seems to be fast like this.

Comment: the CTE will only be called when you reference it in your select query. setting a low RowNum in your where clause limits it so it will only have to do the select until it matches that, increasing it means it will have to do more work

Comment: Seems that method using row_number is used to cut the resultset into pieces? Have you considered using [offset fetch next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184267/in-sql-server-2014-order-by-clause-with-offset-fetch-next-returns-weird-results)? It's only available since sql server 2012 though.

Comment: CTEs are performed over the result set, so the larger the set, the slower the query. (Hence - the name "window function"). There are a number of possible work arounds but they depend on the actual query. First thing I would try however, is to select the result inclusive rownumber into a temporary table (not a table variable) and use that as foundation instead of the CTE. As said - there are other techniques to try such as the using select TOP and NOT IN, or using unions and self-joins to minimize the query and optimize for index. But without actual query it's difficult to advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `FETCH`/`OFFSET` ?

```
select *
from __myResults 
order by ??
offset X - 1
fetch next (X - Y) rows only;
```

You need to adjust the parameters `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I just realized that we have to support MS SQL 2008 :(

Comment: I just tested it anyway. The maximum time it takes now, is not slower than the initial query! Thanks. So it's probably understandable, that the whole query has to be scanned even if offset is being used.

Comment: @ims1234 . . . Do you have an index on the columns in the `order by`?